# What happens to the zeroth Landau level of monolayer graphene with broken $A$-$B$ sublattice symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, electronic-band-theory, graphene

The (non-interacting) Hamiltonian of an electron in monolayer graphene near the $K$ point in the Brillouin Zone can be approximated as  $H = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & v(p_x-i p_y)\\
v(p_x+i p_y) & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, where $\vec{p}$ is the crystal momentum measured from the $K$ point. The bandstructure is a Dirac cone, $E = \pm v |\vec{p}|$.

Under an out-of-plane magnetic field $B$, the Hamiltonian takes the form, $H = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & v(\pi_x-i \pi_y)\\
v(\pi_x+i \pi_y) & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, where $\pi_{x,y} = p_{x,y} - e A_{x,y}$.

The energyspectrum of this Hamiltonian are the Landau levels with energy $E_{n,\pm} = \pm \hbar \omega_c \sqrt{n }$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and an eigenvalue (non-degenerate) at $n = 0$.
This can be shown by squaring the Hamiltonian, and noticing that we have terms of the form $(\pi_x^2 + \pi_y^2)$, which is related to the Hamiltonian of a non-relativistic free electron in a magnetic field, i.e., the regular Landau level problem.

When there is an $A$-$B$ sublattice asymmetry, the Hamiltonian takes the form $H = \begin{bmatrix}
U & v(\pi_x-i \pi_y)\\
v(\pi_x+i \pi_y) & -U
\end{bmatrix}$

The eigenvalues of this Hamiltonian are, $E_{n,\pm} = \pm \sqrt{U^2 + n \hbar^2 \omega_c^2}$, for $n \in \{0,1,2,...\}$ (can be shown using the squaring trick mentioned before).

Clearly, as $U$ is adiabatically turned on, the Landau levels at non-zero energies get shifted as $ \pm \sqrt{n \hbar^2 \omega_c ^2} \rightarrow \pm \sqrt{U^2 + n \hbar^2 \omega_c^2}$ (for $n \neq 0$), and the density of states at these levels remain unchanged.

What happens to the zeroth Landau level? Does it split into two to form the new Landau levels at $E = \pm U$? In other words, will the density of states of the Landau levels at $E = \pm U$ be half of the density of states at the original Landau level at zero energy?

Comment: Your Hamiltonian is not hermitian. The upper-right element should be $p_x-ip_y$. I think the $n=0$ LL has two sets of eigenstates, one entirely supported on the $A$ sublattice, and the other on $B$. Adding a sublattice potential simply splits the two sets, so they now become two LLs with $E=\pm U$.

Comment: @MengCheng I figured it out. Just because $H^2$ has eigenvalue $U^2$ does not necessarily mean $H$ will have eigenvalues $\pm U$. It turns out that in the $K$ valley, only eigenvalue $U$ (supported by sublattice A) can exist, and in the $K'$ valley, only eigenvalue $-U$ (sublattice B) is allowed. Also, thank you for pointing out the hermitian typo.